# How can I sort files by date created in VS Code's Explorer View?

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-code

In the Explorer it sorts the files in alphabetic order, I wanted to know if it was possible to make it sort the files by date created or the reverse of date created. If it is could somebody please inform me? Thanks.

There was no option for sort by date created or the reverse in the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, no. There's the `explorer.sortOrder` setting:

```json
// Controls the property-based sorting of files and folders in the Explorer. When `explorer.fileNesting.enabled` is enabled, also controls sorting of nested files.
//  - default: Files and folders are sorted by their names. Folders are displayed before files.
//  - mixed: Files and folders are sorted by their names. Files are interwoven with folders.
//  - filesFirst: Files and folders are sorted by their names. Files are displayed before folders.
//  - type: Files and folders are grouped by extension type then sorted by their names. Folders are displayed before files.
//  - modified: Files and folders are sorted by last modified date in descending order. Folders are displayed before files.
//  - foldersNestsFiles: Files and folders are sorted by their names. Folders are displayed before files. Files with nested children are displayed before other files.
"explorer.sortOrder": "default",
```

There's no option to sort by date created, but you can [raise a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking for this.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.